# Go: execute bash script

Tags: bash, go

How do I execute a bash script from my Go program? Here's my code:

Dir Structure:

```
/hello/
  public/
    js/
      hello.js
  templates
    hello.html

  hello.go
  hello.sh
```

hello.go

```
cmd, err := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "hello.sh")
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

When I run hello.go and call the relevant route, I get this on my console:

`exit status 127
output is`

I'm expecting ["a", "b", "c"]

I am aware there is a similar question on SO: [Executing a Bash Script from Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25834277/executing-a-bash-script-from-golang), however, I'm not sure if I'm getting the path correct. Will appreciate help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`exec.Command()` returns a struct that can be used for other commands like `Run`

If you're only looking for the output of the command try this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    out, err := exec.Command("date").Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("The date is %s\n", out)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use CombinedOutput() instead of Output(). It will dump standard error result of executed command instead of just returning error code.
See:
[How to debug "exit status 1" error when running exec.Command in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159704/how-to-debug-exit-status-1-error-when-running-exec-command-in-golang)

Answer (score 0):

Check the example at http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command

You can try by using an output buffer and assigning it to the Stdout of the cmd you create, as follows:

```
var out bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &out
```

You can then run the command using

```
cmd.Run()
```

If this executes fine (meaning it returns nil), the output of the command will be in the `out` buffer, the string version of which can be obtained with

```
out.String()
```