# Run go test using Golang's exec library

Tags: go, cmd, command, exec, go-testing

I am trying to run `go test` command using the [exec](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec) library as this.

```
output, err := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "go test -v -run TestX ./test/*").Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.GetLogger().Error(err.Error())
    }
```

It is failing with `exit status 1`. The command runs fine from the command line. What am I missing here?

Comment: You should not be using shell globs to provide the arguments to the `go` command. If the commands fails, what is the error output?

Comment: I will be routing the stdout and stderr of the execution to a report by extending the command.

Comment: Ok, so check the stderr output for why the command failed (running the command directly rather than through a shell may provide better feedback and fewer way to fail)

Comment: It just says `exit status 1`. The command does not fail when I execute it directly from the CLI.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/18177139/18012302

Comment: "exit status 1" is the exit error, not the stderr output. You can assign stderr like you mentioned you were going to do anyway, or use `CombinedOutput`, or use `*exec.ExitError.Stderr`, but there's probably more information. You are still likely to get better feedback executing the command directly, there's not really any need to involve a shell here.

Comment: Thanks, everyone! This worked: `exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", "go test -v -run TestX ./test/* > output.txt")`